# Can't Debug WinForm app in VS2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, debugging, target-framework

I am developing a winform app on VS2010 on my home PC . To test it on the computer of my university,  I just changed its Target Framework from .NET Framework 4.0 client profile to .NET Framework 2.0. ( .NET Framework 4.0 client profile was selected by default). After this I run (debug) my app on my home PC and it runs slowly so i decided to change its target framework to previous one.

After changing target framework I cant debug my app ( upon pressing F5 "Build succeeded" is shown on the most left bottom). Although i can run my app by pressing ctrl+F5 but cant debug. I have restarted my VS 2010 but no success was achieved.

Comment: What version of visual studio (express/pro)? Could be that debug/trace constant got removed (in project properties).

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010 ultimate. Can you describe these constant more in detail please?

Comment: These constants are in the build tab of the project properties, having those enabled means program will have debug symbols on. Also make sure that optimize code is turned off to have debugging

Comment: I have these two constants checked and optimize code is turned off too.

Answer (score 0):

Check the msdn link,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

I think, VS 2010 includes only the .NET Framework 4. To target earlier versions of the .NET Framework, you need to install the appropriate framework. If you change it to Framework 2.0, you need to install it to work properly.

Let us know, if this solves.

cheers

Comment: I did the same conversion (.NET Framework 2.0 to .NET Framework 4.0 client profile) on the same IDE installed on my laptop and it didn't make any problem.